# How can I make skyrim audio volume is a bit louder?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I increase Skyrim's Volume?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35452/how-can-i-increase-skyrims-volume)

I've my Windows 7 volume stick at the highest level. Whenever I start Windows 7 I hear the startup sound very load but when I start Skyrim the game volume is very low? I have already put the Skyrim game volume level to the highest position. How can I normalize my Windows 7 volume with Skyrim volume?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem, and apparently others do to. I followed this [guide](http://www.alienwarearena.com/forums/topic/9011/general-discussion/skyrim-volume-too-low-maybe-a-fix-here-worked-for-me-/) and that fixed it for me. Maybe it will help you aswell.

EDIT: As requested, I will C&P the steps explained in the link below:

- On the control panel > hardware and sound > sound menu
- Select your speakers (realtek high definition audio for me) and
  choose > properties > then go to enhancements tab > and check the
  loudness equalization box, then re-launch skyrim, and check for
  differences on audio.
- This helped me but then I went to the SRS tab on the sound menu
  checked to enable SRS technology (this is from realtek HD audio
  controller) and selected the game option then the game really sounded
  really good and noticed I can hear everythig just fine and not with
  max volume

Comment: Maybe you could add a bit of informations coming from that link. Pages moves or goes down, copying information make sure that it'll always be present

Comment: Loudness equalization is always one of my first tweaks to a Windows system. It's not just good for Skyrim, but if you watch video etc. on cheap speakers / headphones or when there is background noise.

Comment: This has a solution now.

https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/103469 for LE
https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/37418 for SE